# VS Code C++ Intellisense is slow after the line #include <iostream>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've just started learning C++ and I wanted to use VS Code, so I installed the C/C++ extension.

C intellisense is working fine, however for C++, the suggestions for the code completions just somehow delayed for about 1-2 secs before showing up, after this line is inserted:

```
#include <iostream>
```

But when I straight away tried to insert keywords/snippets like **main**, **return**, **namespace** etc. without the line `#include <iostream>` at the top of the file, the intellisense worked just fine and the suggestions for the code completion showed up immediately. There's no delay at all.

Why is this happening? Is there anything happening when `#include <iostream>` is inserted, that cause the intellisense to slow down?

(Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I know nothing about C/C++ yet.)

Comment: Yes, `iostream` is being included... ;-) and that's going to be quite a large and complex header.

Comment: @underscore_d Oh I see, thanks a lot.

Comment: There might be another cause, but that seems most likely IMHO

Comment: @underscore_d 